# Use an external text file to populate a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to populate a UILabel with a string made from a txt file, I've read many posts on here and most talk about it being in the Resources file using [NSBundle], but I want it to come from a an external server, like below, but the string is always null.

```
  NSString *filePath = @"http://mydomain.com/textfile.txt";  
  NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL]; 
  NSLog(@"string = %@", string); // is (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can parse the filePath to URL and use [stringWithContentOfUrl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: Sweet, thanks. is looked like this if anyone has the same problem: NSString *filePath = @"http://mydomain.com/textfile.txt";   
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filePath];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];